# backbone not rendering the $el but can reference element directly

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, rendering

This is killing me, being reading the examples on this site but can't figure out why it works like this.
I want to pass back values to my view, which has buttons that you can use to change the values.
If I use the following

```
   this.$el.empty().html(view.el)
```

View.el contains the correct html, but those not render on the screen. If I use the following

```
    $("#handicap").html( view.el);
```

The values get displayed on screen but the events no longer get picked up eventhough if I put an onclick function in the html code it kicks off.

Ideally I would like to get this.$el.empty().html(view.el) working. It has to do with context but can't see why.

I have created a jsbin here http://jsbin.com/iritex/1/edit

If I have to use $("#handicap").html( view.el), do I need to do something special to unbind events. I have tried undelegate everything but that didn't do the trick either.

thanks

Comment: It's difficult to see what you're trying to do ... but one thing I can say is, it seems like you should be using `events`, a `model`, and a `template`.  That would simplify things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put both views into the DOM. Wherever you create the view that above is `this` needs to be inserted into the DOM. If you do that, then the first line will work fine `this.$el.empty().html(view.el)`.

Comment: Okay, I have added app.view.player.render();                          
   $("#handicap").html( app.view.player.el);    which displays okay. I put   $("#handicap").trigger("create");  in to render the icons. However the events on the button don't fire. I thought by putting empty in above it would unbind the events and clear the issue for me

Answer (score 4):

A Backbone View's el property will always contain a reference to a valid DOM object.  However, that DOM object may or may not be in your display tree.  It's up to you to make sure it's in the display tree when you need it to be.  This functionality lets Backbone maintain the state of it's View element without it being rendered to the screen.  You can add and remove a view from the screen efficiently, for example.

There are a few ways to get your View's element into the display tree.

1) Associate the view with an existing DOM element on the page by passing in a jquery selector to the initializer as the "el" property.

```
var view = new MyView({el: '#MyElementSelector'});
```

2) Associate the view with an existing DOM element on the page by hardcoding the jQuery selector it into the view's "el" property.

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#MyElementSelector'
});
```

3) Render it to the page from within another view

```
var view = new MyView();
view.render();
this.$el.empty().html(view.el);
```

If you're interested, I show examples in a [Backbone Demo](https://github.com/jamesor/backbone-demo) I put together.